# Gedit error for non sudo - undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale (undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale)

Tags: permissions, compiling, gedit, emacs

for some reason I am unable to run gedit as a normal user. I get the following error:

```
heberto@heberto-XPS-13:~$ gedit 
gedit: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_surface_set_device_scale
```

On the other hand when I read the command with `sudo` there is no problem and things run as usual. Same deal for `emacs`.

I have Ubuntu 14.04, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem, when I add `/home/silva/anaconda/lib` to `LD_LIBARY_PATH`  before `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` in `~/.bashrc`. Many software failed to start after that.

I removed `/home/silva/anaconda/lib`, and `source ~/.bashrc` again, solved.

Answer (score 1):

This does not solve the question in full but **my particular problem** arose from installing `neuron` with the debian installer that they provide. Removing the following from `.bashrc` file did the job (and of course now I can not access `neuron` but I do not need it anymore)

```
# Neuron
# export PYTHONHOME="/home/heberto/miniconda2"
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/heberto/miniconda2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update the cairo library.

```
conda update cairo
```